# JQuery Datepicker does not work on IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker

I am using a Jquery Datetimepicker.
Details of the Date Time Picker can be found at :
[DateTimePicker Details](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

This date picker is set to appear on Click and is linked to input boxes.
The Asp Code is mentioned below :

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
     <script type="text/javascript">
   
            $(document).ready(function () {
                
                /*DatePicker initializations*/
                var DATEPICKER_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y';
                var DATETIMEPICKER_FORMAT = 'm-d-Y H:i:s';
                var TIMEPICKER_FORMAT = 'g:ia';
                $(function () {
                    $(".datepickerwithicon").datetimepicker({
                        format: DATEPICKER_FORMAT,
                        datepicker: true,
                        timepicker: false,
                        step: 1,
                        allowBlank: true,
                        closeOnDateSelect: true,
                        validateOnBlur: false
                    });

                    $(".datetimepickerwithicon").datetimepicker({
                        format: DATETIMEPICKER_FORMAT,
                        datepicker: true,
                        timepicker: true,
                        step: 5,
                        allowBlank: true,
                        closeOnDateSelect: true,
                        validateOnBlur: false
                    });

                    /* Append calendar icon image. */
                    $('.datepickerwithicon, .datetimepickerwithicon').each(function () {
                        var dateInput = $(this);
                        var newImgId = dateInput.attr('id') + '_icon';
                        $("<img/>", {
                            "src": "Images/calendar-icon.png",
                            "class": "ui-datepicker-trigger",
                            "id": newImgId
                        }).insertAfter(dateInput);

                        $('#' + newImgId).on('click', function () {
                            dateInput.datetimepicker('show');
                        });
                        dateInput.click(function (event) {
                            $('.xdsoft_datepicker.active .xdsoft_calendar').focus();
                        });
                    });

                  
                });

            });

        </script>
   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbStart" runat="server" Text="Start :" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" runat="server" class="datetimepickerwithicon" />&nbsp;
                    </td>
                <td>`
                    <asp:Label ID="lbEnd" runat="server" Text="End :" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" runat="server" class="datetimepickerwithicon"/>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Issue :** The date time picker does not appear on click event on IE 7. However, it works well on all other versions of IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas on how make it working on IE 7 ?

Comment: Please. Unless you have a really really really really really really good reason to want to support IE7, don't support it. it's from 5 june 2008. We live 7 years further. People who use ie7 need to upgrade. like seriously see http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-9900/Microsoft-Internet-Explorer.html Supporting such a vulnerable browser is bad practise and enables people with bad security habits.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets It is a legacy system which utilizes a IE 7 browser. This system is used within intranet alone and with limited access. Unfortunately in this case, upgrade won't be an option

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I tried the same thing here and the only things that I changed were the paths to the CSS and JS files. It worked fine for me. Can you provide me with the error messages that you've been getting in IE? I could work off of that and provide you the solution real quick. :)

Update 2:
Hi there, This is the code that I've used for testing.
I've downloaded the plugin from the source that you provided in your question and ran it as an HTML file. Can you do the same and let me know if it works in your browser? Real sorry if I'm taking up a lot of your time on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
     <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                /*DatePicker initializations*/
                var DATEPICKER_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y';
                var DATETIMEPICKER_FORMAT = 'm-d-Y H:i:s';
                var TIMEPICKER_FORMAT = 'g:ia';
                $(function () {
                    $(".datepickerwithicon").datetimepicker({
                        format: DATEPICKER_FORMAT,
                        datepicker: true,
                        timepicker: false,
                        step: 1,
                        allowBlank: true,
                        closeOnDateSelect: true,
                        validateOnBlur: false
                    });

                    $(".datetimepickerwithicon").datetimepicker({
                        format: DATETIMEPICKER_FORMAT,
                        datepicker: true,
                        timepicker: true,
                        step: 5,
                        allowBlank: true,
                        closeOnDateSelect: true,
                        validateOnBlur: false
                    });

                    /* Append calendar icon image. */
                    $('.datepickerwithicon, .datetimepickerwithicon').each(function () {
                        var dateInput = $(this);
                        var newImgId = dateInput.attr('id') + '_icon';
                        $("<img/>", {
                            "src": "Images/calendar-icon.png",
                            "class": "ui-datepicker-trigger",
                            "id": newImgId
                        }).insertAfter(dateInput);

                        $('#' + newImgId).on('click', function () {
                            dateInput.datetimepicker('show');
                        });
                        dateInput.click(function (event) {
                            $('.xdsoft_datepicker.active .xdsoft_calendar').focus();
                        });
                    });


                });

            });

        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbStart" runat="server" Text="Start :" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" runat="server" class="datetimepickerwithicon" />&nbsp;
                    </td>
                <td>`
                    <asp:Label ID="lbEnd" runat="server" Text="End :" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" runat="server" class="datetimepickerwithicon"/>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sai Ganesh, I am not seeing any errors when I run on IE. The Calender Icon is visible. However, the On Click event doesn't occur. This issue occurs when run on IE7 alone.

Comment: @WebDeveloper, I've updated the answer, can you try running your code as an HTML file instead of running it as an ASP file? If that's the case, then maybe there could be some missing configuration in your ASP Application. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tested the above code. There were no changes in output. Moreover, I wasn't able to identify the difference in the code. Could you be kindly explain me the change in script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was environment related and was not working with the instance of browser available in the environment. The issue was resolved after a patch update and the datetimepicker is visible thereafter.